# How to hash a set of integers, such that we can use the hash to test if a given integer was in the original set?

Tags: hash, encoding, number-theory

Suppose we have a set of integers. Is there a way to hash them into a single value such that, using only the hash, we can test if a given number was in the original set?

What I after is a sort of zero knowledge proof where I can prove a number belonged to the original set without knowing what the original set was.

```cs
// hash a set of integers 
int Hash(Set<int> values) { ... }

// return true, iff n was in the 
// original set that formed the hash
int Test(int hash, int n) { ... }

// given a set of integers..
Set<int> theSet = {1,4,5,7};

// is it possible to create a "hash"..
int theHash = Hash(theSet);    

// such that, using only the hash, we can test 
// if a number was in the original set?
AssertTrue(Test(theHash, 4));
AssertFalse(Test(theHash, 6));
```

Comment: You may want to check out bloom filter, it is something like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, there's no way to do this. Think of it this way: the number of possible sets of (32-bit) integers is 2<sup>2<sup>32</sup></sup>, since every integer either will or will not be in the set, and the number of possible 32-bit integers is 2<sup>32</sup>. There's simply too many sets of integers to generate a unique code for each one.

In order to make this setup mathematically feasible, you'd need to ensure that there are only 2<sup>32</sup> possible sets of integers that you'd ever want to work with. If you only have 32 possible integer values, then this is possible because the number of sets of possible integers exactly matches the number of possible 32-bit integers. You could accomplish this by just encoding your set as a 32-bit bitvector, with each bit indicating whether a specific element is present or absent.